# Is it possible to worship God in forms that aren't sanctioned by any scripture?

Tags: gods, worship, bhakti, ishwara, bhakti-worship

As per what I have heard in Hindu belief, God manifests in front of a devotee in any form that the devotee wants him to. However, from a personal viewpoint, my mind does not find any connection or attraction towards any of the forms of Bhagavan or the devatas which the scriptures mention.

This begs me to ask the question - If I worship God in a certain form that isn't sanctioned by any scripture, would God heed to me and appear before me in that particular form, or will the worship go fruitless?

Comment: There are hundreds of rūpas of many devatās in śāstras, how many have you really seen and read about? Do you know about all of them?

Comment: @Bingming I am aware of the Shanmata devatas and their vibhutis. As for the minor dieties like varuna,indra etc...don't really feel too invested about them.

Comment: No. Vedanta doesn't talk about gods with forms. It rather talks about the self, which is formless and the one that is god. A good summary of Vedanta is via four Mahavakyas - Tat Tvam Asi, Aham Brahasmi, Prajnanam Brahma, and Ayam Atma Brahma. Vedanta only says - know yourself, that's enough. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81v%C4%81kyas

Comment: @User29449 I know that, and the question isn't asking what vedanta talks about or not. It's asking whether it's possible to worship God in a certain form that isn't sanctioned by any scripture or not...

Comment: @Soumya Who are you really invested in then, if the ṣaṇmata devatās, lokapālas, etc. can't make you invested (*which is actually pretty strange for a proper Hindu*) ? What about grāmadevatās, yakṣas or devatās such as say Śāstā (Hariharaputra)?

Comment: @Soumya You can worship a *Brahman* in any form you wish. But yakshas, bhutas, pisachas aren't devtas. They are conscious beings and need specific instructions to worship (or communicate).

Comment: Well, there are some yakṣas, who are worshipped. Kubera is a yakṣa as well as the yakṣapati. And yakṣas do belong to devayoni. Apart from Hindu tradition, in Jaina many yakṣas and yakṣiṇīs, who are śāsanadevatās, are worshipped. @User29449

Comment: @Bingming Even in Buddhism, their worship is acknowledged, *Padmasambhava* used to capture yakshas for protection. *Karnapisachini* Sadhana is an example of a yakshas. There are *veer-vetal sadhana*, most of them are invoked for protection. Apart from material growth and powers, most of such are useless. I know one person closely, he invoked an *apsara* and fell into trouble as he couldn't send her back. I don't know if these are useful or not.

Answer (score 1):

Ishwara/God is not limited to only a few forms. Ishwara can take any form. **For worship, the form of Ishwara does not matter. What matters is the correct understanding of the tattva (nature) of Ishwara.** The tattva of Ishwara comes from scriptures.

Ishwara can be worshipped in any form.

> yē yathā māṅ prapadyantē tāṅstathaiva bhajāmyaham.
> mama vartmānuvartantē manuṣyāḥ pārtha sarvaśaḥ৷৷ Bhagavad Gita 4.11৷৷

> **Whoever resorts to Me in any manner, in the same manner do I favour them;** men experience Me alone in different ways, O Arjuna.

Ishwara has innumerable forms.

> śrī bhagavānuvāca,
> paśya mē pārtha rūpāṇi śataśō.tha sahasraśaḥ.
> nānāvidhāni divyāni nānāvarṇākṛtīni ca৷৷ Bhagavad Gita 11.5৷৷

> 11.5 The Blessed Lord said - O son of Prtha, **behold My forms in (their) hundreds and in thousands**, of different kinds, celestial, and of various colours and shapes.

Ishwara can be formless (unmanifest) too.

> mayā tatamidaṅ sarvaṅ jagadavyaktamūrtinā Bhagavad Gita 9.4.1

> This entire universe is pervaded by Me, in an **unmanifest** form

Ishwara assumes all forms.

> rūpaṃ rūpaṃ pratirūpo babhūva, tadasya rūpaṃ praticakṣaṇāya |
> indro māyābhiḥ pururūpa īyate...Brihadaranyaka upanishad 2.5.19

> **‘(The Lord) transformed Himself in accordance with each form;** that form of His was for the sake of making Him known. The Lord on account of Māyā is perceived as manifold..